# Api platfrom, show possible query parameters in documentation

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I have a GET endpoint, that endpoint can return only a single record, so it's not a collection endpoint, but additionally, I need to be able to apply different optional filters with query parameters, for example:

- deleted - show/hide
- user - search additionally by user id

Som uri will be something like `/product/{$is}?delted=show&user=1`

but how can I describe them to be visible in API documentation UI?

Comment: This is  a great place for API documentation https://www.openapis.org/

Comment: If you are using [`NelmioApiDocBundle`](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) or [zircote/swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) you can use `OpenApi\Attributes\Paremeter("queryParameterName", in: "query")` on your controller method to document query paramters or directly use `OpenApi\Attributes\QueryParameter` (which extends Parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With API-Platform 3, using PHP 8 attributes:

```php
// src/Entity/MyEntity.php
<?php
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model\Operation as ModelOperation;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model\Parameter as ModelParameter;

#[ApiResource(
    new Get(
        openapi: new ModelOperation(
            parameters: [
                new ModelParameter(
                    name: "deleted",
                    in: "query",
                    schema: [
                        "type" => "string",
                        "enum" => ["show", "hide"],
                    ],
                ),
                new ModelParameter(
                    name: "user",
                    in: "query",
                    schema: ["type" => "integer"]
                )
            ],
        ),
    ),
)]
class MyEntity {
    // ...
}
```

The `"in": "query"` indicates that the parameter is located inside the query string (i.e GET parameters set).

When using API-Platform 2, use `openapi_context` instead of `openapi` and passes an array of array instead of an array or `ModelParameter` objects.

More information about [OpenApi here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/).